# Contain a css animation to only an image and not over the entire contents of a page

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a shimmer effect over a logo.  While I can do that, the shimmer effect is going outside the bounds of the .png and can be seen on top of the background of the page as well.  Can anyone assist?  `

```css
body {
  width: 608px;
  height: 342px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url(http://www.whitewaterconnect.com/images/backgrounds/TriangularBackground.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: jobber;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.splash-logo {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  content: url(http://www.whitewaterconnect.com/images/splash-logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}

.shine {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.shine:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  animation: 5s myani linear infinite;
}

@keyframes myani {
  0% {
    top: -150%;
    left: -150%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 150%;
    left: 150%;
  }
}

div.splash-text {
  font-family: jobber;
  font-size: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 825px;
  left: 655px;
  color: #0099CC;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
</div>

<div class="shine">
</div>

<div class="splash-logo">
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

For future reference if anyone else runs into this issue, here's I went about fixing this.

I basically created a "raised" background with z-index set to 10.   I recreated my background with a transparent area where the logo should go.   Effectively, creating a mask to fit around my logo.   So, the bottom layer was the logo, then the shimmer effect and then the background on top.